# Detect Google TV without using user agent string

Tags: javascript, google-tv

We have a client that wants their content on Google TV (via the Chrome Browser), but is legally restricted from allowing it on the "regular web".  So we want to detect Google TV Browser via Javascript, and if it is not, disallow playing the content.

The first thought was to check the user agent string, but apparently they don't like that because it would be too easy for a user to change their user agent string on their web browser so it pretends to be the Google TV browser.

Is there something else we could check for that is a little harder (or at least less obvious) to fake?  I know any solution can be hacked around if someone tries hard enough, and that is ok.

Comment: Funny, the client is trying to get around a legal agreement by saying Chromo on Google TV is not the "regular web" but they're troubled by users breaking the default browser configs. Sounds like you're helping them break the law and will be the scape goat when some has an issue with what the "web" is.

Comment: Not helping anyone break the law.  If anything it is finding where the grey area of a contract is.  The contract has language that differentiates TV's from Desktop computers.  Worst case scenario the content owner would simply tell them to not support Google TV at all.

Comment: This can't be all, but may help. Have your viewers to accept your term and condition which they have to agree they are using google tv for viewing the content.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some things you can do since you only want to ensure that you are detecting who is **NOT** using a GoogleTV browser.  Certainly these can be spoofed but they are quite a bit harder than just using a different user-agent string.

Basically, the idea would be to test for certain JavaScript object support (see this page: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/objdetect3.shtml for some ideas).  An example of this would be testing for the presence of `window.opera` which would indicate that the browser was indeed Opera and definitely NOT a GoogleTV.

To that end, I've written a small fiddle example that cannot be faked by user-agent switching in all the modern browsers and requires a more sophisticated mechanism to bypass.  I tested and it does pass on a Google TV.

http://jsfiddle.net/XBT4w/2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any better ways then what Google [suggests](https://developers.google.com/tv/faq#detectvisitors):

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;

function isGoogleTvBrowser(useragent) {
  return Boolean(useragent.match(/(Large Screen)|GoogleTV/i));
}
```

Although obviously, the user agent string can be faked extremely easily.

Comment: Yeah that won't work because "faked extremely easily" doesn't satisfy the lawyers. :( They seem to be ok with "faked with a bit of difficulty" though.

Comment: @rob: That's understandable, I just thought I'd offer up some concrete documentation. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can come up with, especially in JavaScript, is going to be **very easy** to fake, because one can trivially (with console) paste code that will inject any value into any location.