# Feature detection instead of user-agent sniffing on TV

Tags: responsive-design, user-agent, google-tv, apple-tv

My team is considering developing for TV, and thought of designing a tailored "10-foot UI" to present our content differently on TV-sets.

The only way I see it happening at this point is by sniffing user-agents to detect where the users are coming from. I see that there are some user-agents available for TVs, for instance:

**AppleTV:**

`User-Agent: iTunes-AppleTV/4.1`

**Google TV:**

`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; GoogleTV x.x.x; LG Google TV Build/000000) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.77 Safari/534.24`

*However, we don't want to use user-agents unless we must*.

On this often referred to article by Mozilla Developer Network, [Browser detection using the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) they adamantly discourage the use of user-agents sniffing to provide special content, advising one to rather use feature detection.

**Is there a single, stable and well-supported feature on TV browsers/systems that is easily detectable?** If yes, what would it be?

Comment: I use user agents to show/hide content from specific devices, but it sounds like what you want here is something more like feature-detection and media queries using libraries  Modernizr and/or a responsive css framework (Bootstrap/Foundation).  This way you can display your UI differently on large screens, regardless of what's being used (eg, someone with their computer hooked up to their large screen lcd would get the same view as someone using google/apple tv)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no standard yet on identifying browsers User Agent is used a lot. If you want to avoid doing this you could try to use the navigator object like this:

```
var browser = navigator.appName;
var version = navigator.appVersion;
```

Comment: Hi Krispy, cheers for your taking the time to answer my question! It was exciting to find that you currently work at Google TV, so I'll take your advice to heart. I won't be accepting your answer yet because it doesn't answer the main question and because this approach might not be as reliable as using TV `user-agents` explicitly, at least not at this point. I'm sure others will find this approach useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is use user agent. There is a good auxiliary way suggested by the first answer in this SO post.

[Detect Google TV without using user agent string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538143/detect-google-tv-without-using-user-agent-string)

The offered fiddle there works well on Vizio box that I tested.

var isGoogleTv = true;
var allResults = '';

function tryTest(name, testResult) {
    var result = (testResult ? 'succeeded' : 'failed');
    allResults += '' + name + '';
    isGoogleTv = isGoogleTv && testResult;
}

function renderResults() {
    document.write('

  ');
      document.write(allResults);
      document.write('

');
    if (isGoogleTv) { 
        document.write('

## Google TV detected!

'); 
    } else { 
        document.write('

## NOT GOOGLE TV!

');
    }
}

tryTest('is user-agent GoogleTV', Boolean(navigator.userAgent.match(/(Large Screen)|GoogleTV/i)));
tryTest('is not opera', Boolean(window.opera==undefined));
tryTest('is not IE6+', Boolean(!(document.compatMode && document.all)));
tryTest('is not platform Win', !Boolean(navigator.platform.match(/Win/)));
tryTest('is vendor Google', Boolean(navigator.vendor.match(/Google/)));







tryTest('is not IE', false);






    renderResults();

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and think many people will find it useful, but I can't accept it as right because it involves `user agent` and because I originally asked for a feature detection for all (or most) TV devices. This solution doesn't cut as an answer for the question, but as I already mentioned, I'm sure someone will find it useful for their context...